# Accessing VirtualBox guest web server via IPv6

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtualbox, ipv6

Host: Mac with Chrome

Guest: Ubuntu 16.04, bridged adapter

Guest:

```
karl@karl-VirtualBox:~$ ip -6 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::xxxx:xxxx:11a:890e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I can access the server on the guest fine on the guest via `http://localhost:8080`. However, I am having no luck accessing it either from the guest nor the host in IPv6.

Tried: http://[fe80::xxxx:xxxx:11a:890e]:8080

[image]

Comment: The `/64` is not part of the address, so you should leave that bit out.

Comment: @JohanMyréen I see, updated, still same error however.

Comment: IPv6 link-local addresses are a bit problematic, because a host can have several network interfaces, and has no way to know which interface to use to reach another link-local host. This can be circumvented by specifying the interface name after the address, for example `telnet fe80:1234:bbfb:4ec0:d1e1%eth0 80`. Unfortunately, browsers don't seem to support this notation. Another possibility is to use mDNS and connect to the server by name. `systemd-resolved` or `avahi` can function as mDNS responders, and I suppose Macs function as mDNS clients out of the box, since mDNS is from Apple.